# mod rewrite, trying to show a default image for ALL requests from a certain domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I have, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain.com/ .*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mydomain.com/new-pic.jpg [L]
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing slash before the dot in dot-com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ .*$ [NC]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work.

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?domain\.com/ .*$ [NC]  
    RewriteRule ^.*\.jpg$ http://mydomain.com/new-pic.jpg [L]

Answer (score 0):

Redirect your 404 page to this image.